# What is the max FD value in select?

Tags: c++, tcp, lwip

I'm working with Lwip and 2 thread Tcp with each one its own port and as well 2 thread Udp with each one its own port.

For every `lwip_select` a `maxFd +1` is required , I want to be sure to use the right one.

Right now in every thread , each one check its last FD value, I'm not sure it's enough

```
 timeval timeout;
 timeout.tv_sec = 0;
 timeout.tv_usec = 0;

 fd_set readset;
 FD_ZERO(&readset);
 FD_SET(_clientFd, &readset);

 if (lwip_select(_clientFd+1, &readset, 0, 0, &timeout) > 0)
```

I thought of using a `int array[30]` to store Fd coming from `lwip_socket`, `lwip_connect` and reset to 0 for every `lwip_close`
so that for every ask for `maxFd`, I'd go through the array to find its max value

I expect to find the right `maxFd` for the `lwip_select`

Comment: Not very clear what you want. If every thread has its own descriptor why do you have to find the max?

Comment: The `FD_SETSIZE` macro is the maximum + 1 file descriptor that can be used with `select()`. If you have a lot of descriptors, you're better off with `poll()` or an OS-specific mechanism like linux's epoll or the BSDs's kqueue (I have no idea how they might interact with this library).

Comment: I thought the descriptor was common with the whole TcpIp stack so would be shared with the other thread, isn't it the case ? there is no poll in lwip